# How to move files and folder across different svn repository

Tags: tortoisesvn

I tried using svnadmin dump to move files from one svn repository path to the another svn repo with command

`svnadmin dump path/to/source > source.dmp`

in windows 64 bit.I am getting error

`(svnadmin: E720003: Can't open file 'format': The system cannot find the path specified).`

I am using svnadmin,

> version 1.8.9 (r1591380) compiled May  6 2014, 20:28:35 on
>   x86-microsoft-windows

Can someone help to resolve this error? thanks in advance

Comment: Is `/path/to/source` the filesystem path to your repository, or a working copy?

Comment: Path to my working copy in windows.

Comment: Then you can't do that. `svnadmin dump` must be run against a repository database directory, not a working copy. You can point `svnadmin rdump` at a repository URL.